# What else can you call an acme fitting?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, terminology, machine-elements, joining

Selling products on Amazon, I've had a listing pulled over "trademark violation" for mentioning that an HVAC sets come with acme fittings and/or acme adapters.

**a)** Is there any way that this trademark hit is actually valid given that acme/Acme/ACME fittings are a 127 year old product that has been a national [ANSI/ASME standard](https://willrich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/ANSI-ASME-B1.5-Acme-standard.pdf) for nearly 9 decades and are used generically across the entire field?

**b)** What else could they possibly be called? 29° trap fittings? Is there anyone who would search for that or even understand it if they happened across it?

Comment: Certainly the "what do you call this aspect" is more valid here. Crossposted [a related question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/76537/pulled-off-amazon-on-a-specious-trademark-claim) to the Law stack to see if my Googling was insufficient and if there _are_ ways that the legal claim being made could be valid despite no one in engineering seeming to know about that yet. I'd still appreciate your all's help as far as alternative names and industry standards and thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for the laugh. Sorry you ran into a bunch of idiots. Acme threads aren't a trademark outside of Warner Brothers cartoons. Get a lawyer to write Amazon a letter insisting that they remove the AC from all their delivery vehicles immediately -referencing the letter they sent to you. And post their letter on HVAC forums suggesting everyone tell Amazon "I can't work on that AC - trademark violation."

Comment: a lot of people just like using any reason to take out a potential competitor.  you can mention compliance to the national standard as "fitting threads compliant to..." good laugh indeed considering amazon itself looks for popular $-making items and makes their own version to kick their sellers out of that market.

Comment: There are several brands with "ACME" in the name, that might be what's triggering the violation. Your option b) seems to be the easiest solution until your issue gets resolved. McMaster openly refers to them as Acme fwiw